# Switch position of absolute positioned elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I was looking for a solution to shift div2 to div1's position if div1 has `display:none`. When this happens, I want div3 to shift to div2's position as its already been shifted to div1's position. How do I achieve this in CSS or jquery?
After its been shifted, can I reactive div1 as `display:block`?

```css
#bg {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    left: 0%;
}
#bg-1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
    }

 #bg-2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 177%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
#bg-3 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 254%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```
 <div id="bg">
        <img id="bg-1" src="img/a.png" />
        <img id="bg-2" src="img/b.png" />
        <img id="bg-3" src="img/c.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: give html please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

You have a bit of problem with using `position: absolute;` and  `left` in `%`, but this is solution if you are using it this way:

```
    if ($("#bg-1").css('display') == 'none') {
// if bg1 is display none
    
    $("#bg-2").css('display', "none");
// put bg-2 do display  none also to be able to read % in left,
// this wont work  without this, because  if elements is displayed it will 
//show this CSS value in pixels, current position in screen

      console.log($("#bg-2").css('left'));
      console.log($("#bg-1").css('left'));
      
      var bg1Pos = $("#bg-1").css('left');
      var bg2Pos = $("#bg-2").css('left');
 // read left value from CSS     

      $("#bg-1").css('left', bg2Pos);
      $("#bg-2").css('left', bg1Pos);
// switch them    
 
    $("#bg-2").show();
//show bg-2 back
    }
```

**Working example:**

```js
if ($("#bg-1").css('display') == 'none') {

$("#bg-2").css('display', "none");

  console.log($("#bg-2").css('left'));
  console.log($("#bg-1").css('left'));
  
  var bg1Pos = $("#bg-1").css('left');
  var bg2Pos = $("#bg-2").css('left');
  
  $("#bg-1").css('left', bg2Pos);
  $("#bg-2").css('left', bg1Pos);
  
$("#bg-2").show();
}
```

```css
#bg-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#bg-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#bg-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg">
  <div id="bg-1">bg-1</div>
  <div id="bg-2">bg-2</div>
  <div id="bg-3">bg-3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot this worked. It will be very complicated if there are multiple divs that are hidden.

Comment: @Saif Np. Not really, just expand this on  multiple divs with your logic. Or this could be written different, this was made for question asked, you could target all divs with display none, and all that are visible, and use for-each and arrays to make it work an all together (yes a bit more complicated, so just make multiple if's, or ask new question and make new HTML markup representing that issue). But that is different question and logic that was not included in this question.

Answer (score 0):

all css you need is:

```
#bg img { width: 100%; display: block}
#bg-1 { display: none; }
```

if you add `#bg{ padding-top: 56.25%;}` you get a blank space above images
if you apply `img{ height: 100%; width: 100%;}` it will smash aspect ratio of your images
if you apply `position: absolute` to any item you loose control of it
if you apply `position: fixed` to any element it will be really static

You don't need do any funky stuff. Behaviour you want is natural for html, just stop breaking it